# A word or a phrase for this logical fallacy

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests

What is another word or phrase for when someone tries to dismiss an argument by simply claiming it is extreme, without offering any evidence or counterargument?

Comment: Arguments are often addressed by testing the limits.

Comment: So, when someone just claims an argument is invalid without explaining why? That's called "ignoring what the other person says."

Comment: That it is too extreme is sometimes a valid answer.  To go further than that, sometimes, is a foolish waste of time.  On the other hand....

Answer (score 2):

For a good rundown on logical fallacies, check out https://carm.org/logical-fallacies-or-fallacies-argumentation.

What you're describing might be construed in several ways, depending on how the dispute actually unfolds.

Among the good candidates are these:

> Ad Hominem - Attacking the individual instead of the argument.

In this case, if the arguer labels his opponent an extremist, it may be viewed as a personal attack.

> Appeal to the Popular - Urging the hearer to accept a position because a majority of people hold to it.

"Extreme" implies that the thing so described lies outside of the tolerance of most people, so by extension labeling a position as "extreme" appeals to popularity, or rather the lack thereof.

> Red Herring - Introducing a topic not related to the subject at hand.

If the accusation of extremeness is really irrelevant to the subject at hand, this may be the name of the fallacy you're thinking of.